# ArgumentError at / Unknown key: :conditions after upgrading to Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm receiving this error after upgrading to Rails 4.1.4:

> ArgumentError at Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table

for this line in app/models/app.rb:

```
letsrate_rateable "quality"
```

I'm using this gem: `https://github.com/benmanns/letsrate`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you are using the fork instead of main branch? This fork is inactive for over 2 years

Comment: It was the only one that worked before I upgraded to Rails 4.1.1.

Comment: Try switching back to the main branch, this error has been fixed there.